# How do I gain access to the R&D Lab?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I am in the third office, Y13 M6 W3, with 6.5M in the bank, and 5 employees plus myself.

How do I gain access to the R&D Lab?

Comment: I clarified your question, as "moving (the screen) to (view) the R&D lab" is a very valid but completely different question. If I've interpreted anything wrong please correct it.

Answer (score 8):

As per the [Game Dev Tycoon wikia page](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/R%26D_lab) you need to be in the third office (I'm assuming you're not counting the starting 'garage' as an office, in which case you'd need to be in the fourth "office") and meet the following requirements;

> Must have access to the third office and have at least one designer specialist. Each additional designer specialist will reduce the cost of development (by 100K each at maximum rate).

The "third office" is the office that looks like this;

[image]

In order to get a designer specialist, you must [train](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Training) at least one of your employees to have 700 in design, followed by the 'Designer Specialist' course (available in the training menu).